# JavaFX Application file upload

Tags: javafx-2

I have my javaFX application running on a Tomcat server  and the client access to this app by a browser. I want to create an  file on the server side. How can i do that? Because at the moment if i use a path for example "/Users/username/Desktop" it will create the file on the client Desktop. I want to create this file on the server desktop. I'm using javaFX 2.2 on netbeans 7.2.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the use of the library [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/). See too this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226503/using-apache-commons-fileupload).

Regards