# How to read a Excel file that is selected and submitted in JSP form?

Tags: java, excel, jsp

The end user will select an excel file on executing the below jsp program.

```
   <form action="?? " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 

    Upload File:
   <input name="file" type="file" id="file"><br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
   <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"/>   
   </form>
```

The excel sheet will be in a specified format which need to be read and compared with the contents of Database.

My query here is how should I proceed with this once the user browses the excel file and submits the jsp form.

How the excel sheet can be invoked to a java program and please explain me the steps of doing the same. Am a beginner in java and I would be so thankful if your answer is self explanatory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate Excel documents with the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) API.

---

Your action should redirect you to a servlet which will handle the file. You'll need to handle multipart files, you can use [Apache file upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to do this.

---

**Resources :**

- [Apache POI - Case studies](http://poi.apache.org/casestudies.html)
- [Apache POI - FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html)
- [Reading and Writing Excel Files with POI](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html)
- [How do I upload a file to my servlet or JSP?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=160)
- [How to use apache fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [Learning Apache POI for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253779/learning-apache-poi-for-java)
- [Reading date values from excel cell using POI HSSF API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861877/reading-date-values-from-excel-cell-using-poi-hssf-api)
- [Managing file uploads in JSP/Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220135/managing-file-uploads-in-jsp-servlets)

Comment: I really dont know how to handle such API and how it should be connected with the present jsp progrmam. please advise

Comment: See resources and linked questions.

Comment: yeah I will learn from those resources. But could you please let me know how to connect that program to my present jsp program. What must be given in <form action="" ?

Comment: Updated, you should clarify your question.

Comment: I am a beginner and I am completely unaware of Servelet concepts. Is there any easier way to achieve the task?

Comment: I'm afraid there is not. You really should look at all the links I gave (and the links in there), you'll find every information you need to do this.

Comment: I have written a Servelet program already which has a doPost(request, response) method in it. How to compile that Servelet program? Is there any unique way of compiling or it can be done as normal java program?

Comment: What you need here, is to learn first how to do web applications in java. You should seek tutorials like this one : http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html

Answer (score 0):

Apache already invented a library to read excel sheet. Its name is [Apache Poi](http://poi.apache.org/). It's free and it's well documented. And of course a sample code is available